# how to call a function to another function in julia?

Tags: function, julia

I am writing a code in julia but I am unable to call a function from another function. Code is:

```
function add(x, y)
    if x == 3 && y ==1
        z =0
    else x == 0 && y ==0
        z =1
    end
    return z
end

function width(a, b, c)
    add(x,y)
    .....
end
```

The variables in add function will be used in width function but as I am new to julia, I am unable to call add in the other function. Kindly guide.
Edit:
I tried declaring with the z but it also didn't worked

```
struct z 
    a::Int 
    b::Int 
end
```

Comment: Maybe `add(x,y)` should be `add(a,b)` because `x` and `y` are the names of `add` parameters and they need to be filled with locally accessible values (such as `a`,`b`,`c`) ?

Comment: You must call the `add` function with the variables that are actually available inside the `width` function. For example `add(a, b)`. This has nothing to do with Julia, it's general in programming languages.

Comment: Ah, sorry I did that mistake. I tried again but again error occurred:
ERROR: LoadError: UndefKeywordError: keyword argument z not assigned

Comment: I tried declaring with the z as:
struct z
    a::Int
    b::Int
end
but it also didn't worked

Comment: That error indicates you have another definition for the function, something lke `add(x, y; z)`. Post the code *as you currently have it* in the question and we can figure out why the error happens.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question, please check

Comment: Hi. This segment of the code is not useful to debug the problem. Please show your function definitions as you currently have them. Also, make sure to first restart your REPL or Jupyter session, run the code one more time, and check that the error happens in that fresh session. If it does occur, post the code that leads to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code that are not related to Julia per se. First problem in the `add` function: if `x == 3 && y == 1` the output should be `z = 0`, else if `x == 0 && y == 0`, actually the `if` was missing, the output should be `z = 1`. Now what will be the output if, e.g., `x = 1 && y == 1`? The answer is `nothing` and `z` will be undefined.

To fix the `add` function, you should add a default branch for the if-else.

```
function add(x, y)
    if x == 3 && y == 1
        z = 0
    elseif x == 0 && y == 0
        z = 1
    else 
        z = -1 # some default
    end
    return z
end
```

The same function could be written more concisely as:

```
function add(x, y)
    x == 3 && y == 1 && return 0
    x == 0 && y == 0 && return 1
    return -1 # some default
end
```

which can even be written in a one-liner like this:

```
add(x, y) = x == 3 && y == 1 ? 0 : x == 0 && y == 0 ? 1 : -1 # some default
```

The second problem is with the `width` function. `x` and `y` are not defined inside the body of the `width` function. So, you can't call `add(x, y)`. It should be `z = add(a, b)` where `z` should be used in subsequent calculations. Finally, check what the third argument `c` is for, otherwise, remove it.

```
function width(a, b, c)
    z = add(a, b)
    .....
end
```